# postgresql disable DELETE on replication servers

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, master-slave

Okay, short summary: For security purposes we want to disable the delete functionality on our replication instances.

Now, because these instances are read-only, we cannot revoke the DELETE command on tables, nor can we create a rule to do nothing on DELETE.

Is there an alternative way to force the replication server to NOT obey delete commands from the master server?

Comment: No. Consider what would happen for a table with a unique index if the value of a deleted row is later re-INSERT or UPDATEd - it would work on the primary and fail on the replicas. That's a no-go.

Comment: I don't mind if it causes the replication server to crash - that is what i intent. the master server shouldn't be able to alter the slave server, as far as deleting records go. If the master attempts to delete, the slave server crashes / does not obey. It is merely used as a fail-safe, I intent to use it for nothing more than that.

Comment: If the replica is read only, how could the delete be performed anyway, whether it is "allowed" or not?  All you would do is fail with a different error?

Comment: read-only as in it takes all the constraints from the master server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible with streaming (physical) replication.

However, you can use logical replication to exclude deletes from replication. But you will be responsible for cleaning up any replication conflicts yourself, because any such conflict would stop replication.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be what i'm looking for. I assume this can be done synchronously? Any documentation you would recommend me to check out?

Comment: It seems that we can set a publish flag on the master server of what to relay, (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE), but we cannot tell the slave server to not obey/obey this. In other words, if the master server suddenly changes it's publishing rules, that is to say, they change from (publish= 'insert) to (publish = 'insert', 'delete'), there is no way to defend the slave server from this change...?

Comment: I guess we can make everything a bit more difficult, and replicate the replication server (#2), with just publishing inserts, that way, only slave server #1 is effected.

Comment: Yes, this is controlled by the publication. Yes, you can do synchronous logical replication, but the usual caveats apply: 1) have short network latency between the nodes 2) expect a sharp decrease in write performance 3) if you have less then two synchronous standby servers, your overall availability will decrease.